# How to Clear a Gdoc and write in the begining at the document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Hi I have a prob with my Scritp GAS.
I clear all my Google Doc but when I Write new DATA on my Google doc.  my DATA is on the Second page.

Is there an other way for clear a Google Doc  ?

```
function eraseContent(docId){
```

`var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);  doc.setText(" ");`

```
}
```

regards

Comment: This code seems to work, you don't even have to use a space , an empty string will do the job. Alternatively you can use something like doc.getBody().editAsText().setText('');I tested both and didn't had the issue you mention.